# Creating different structures of the same table in a different excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet with a table that has membership names, birthdays and other information. I need to be able to view this information in more than one way.

This is to say that, for example, some day I might need to have the column of "first name" come before the column of "last name". In another I might the two to be combined. I know how to make this changes, but here's my dilemma:

Instead of having to change my table every time. I'm hoping there is a way to have the main data in one table in one sheet. And for there to be a way to show this same table in different sheets. I could then label the secondary sheets and arrange each of them in ways that I might need them. The trick being that when I update the main sheet, I should then be able to Data/"Refresh All" and the other sheets should update.

This seems like it's probably pretty rudimentary so I am sure there is a way to do it easily, but I don't think I'm using the right words in my search to find the correct steps.

Thank you in advance. The help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like the kind of task you should be doing in a database, not a spreadsheet.

Comment: You can reference = the table to the New Sheet and based on the new Sheet to create the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA, not sure of a non-hacky method. Pivot tables won't work if wanting to concatenate fields. However, you could create all possible scenarios in this master table and then use pivot tables. I'm not real familiar with power queries. Here's one method using vlookups against a customer id field.

Master Data should be a Table, with a unique value for each member. Pretend everything starting in column G are in other sheets.

Cell G3 formula:

```
=IFERROR(Table2[@ID],"")
```

Cell H3 formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($G3,Table2[#All],3,FALSE),"")
```

Cell I3 formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($G3,Table2[#All],2,FALSE),"")
```

Cell M3 formula:

```
=IFERROR(CONCAT(VLOOKUP(L3,Table2[#All],3,FALSE),",",VLOOKUP(L3,Table2[#All],2,FALSE)),"")
```

Cell N3 formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(L3,Table2,4,FALSE)="Red","Yes","No"),"")
```

**UPDATE: I don't typically use tables and just realized you can probably mimic formula in G3 for other columns. So, that's a bit easier.**

..And so on. Drag these formulas down far, perhaps double the number of members you have. That way, when you add a new Member to the Master sheet, the other sheets are automatically updated. The iferror keeps it clean.

Just make sure to periodically check the other sheets to make sure the formulas are dragged down far enough. And then you may want to Protect those other sheets to make sure people don't mess with the formulas.

[image]